# Expand or contract button image to fit text

Tags: css, moodle

Im creating a moodle theme and i have a button image that i need to use for my navigation links but cant seem to figure out how to expand and contract the button image to fit the link text

```
.headingblock {
    padding-bottom:1px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-top: 1px; /*background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8d969c;*/
    font-size:12px !important;
    background: url([[pix:theme|top-nav-link1]]) no-repeat;
}

h2.headingblock {
    background-color:#8d969c;
}
```

Comment: please provide a link ya code

Comment: .headingblock {
 padding-bottom:1px;
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-right: 2px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 /*background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8d969c;*/
 font-size:12px !important;
 background: url([[pix:theme|top-nav-link1]]) no-repeat;
}

h2.headingblock{
 background-color:#8d969c;
 }

Comment: i need a code in my css that will expand or contract the size of the image based on the length of the link text

Answer (score 0):

```
.headingblock input[type="button"]{
    background-image:url([[pix:theme|search_button_bg3]]) !important;
background-color:#8d969c;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 58px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
}
```